# How do you disable Okta auto configuration for testing?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, okta

I'm using [this Okta Spring Boot starter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.okta.spring/okta-spring-boot-starter/1.4.0), but I cannot disable the auto configuration for integration testing. Normally, you would do something like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, OktaOAuth2AutoConfig.class })
class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

However, the OktaOAuth2AutoConfig class is package protected and you cannot disable it. I've tried component scanning filters and a bunch of other techniques, but the problem is that it is still loading and requiring `okta.oauth2.issuer` (along with client id and secret) and calling it to make sure it is a valid OAuth2 provider. I don't want this functionality in case the tests have to run somewhere where the auto config can't call the issuer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to mock things so OIDC discovery can happen. I show how to do it for a JHipster app in [this blog post](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/15/testing-spring-security-oauth-with-junit#how-to-handle-oidc-discovery-in-spring-boot-integration-tests). Since you're using the Okta Spring Boot starter, I'm guessing you can do something like this.

1. Create a `TestSecurityConfiguration.java` class.

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class TestSecurityConfiguration {
    private final ClientRegistration clientRegistration;

    public TestSecurityConfiguration() {
        this.clientRegistration = clientRegistration().build();
    }

    @Bean
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
    }

    private ClientRegistration.Builder clientRegistration() {
        Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        metadata.put("end_session_endpoint", "https://example.org/logout");

        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("okta")
            .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .scope("read:user")
            .authorizationUri("https://example.org/login/oauth/authorize")
            .tokenUri("https://example.org/login/oauth/access_token")
            .jwkSetUri("https://example.org/oauth/jwk")
            .userInfoUri("https://api.example.org/user")
            .providerConfigurationMetadata(metadata)
            .userNameAttributeName("id")
            .clientName("Client Name")
            .clientId("client-id")
            .clientSecret("client-secret");
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return mock(JwtDecoder.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        return new AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientService);
    }
}
```

Then in classes that use `@SpringBootTest`, configured this class as a configuration source.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {YourMainApp.class, TestSecurityConfiguration.class})
```

Another blog post, [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Testing Spring Boot APIs and Angular Components with WireMock, Jest, Protractor, and Travis CI](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/02/testing-spring-boot-angular-components), has some additional information on mocking APIs for testing. Specifically, see [Mock Okta’s API with WireMock](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/02/testing-spring-boot-angular-components#mock-oktas-api-with-wiremock).

Comment: Thanks man. Your blog posts are extremely helpful. I think I have a ways to go to understanding OAuth2 before I can fully understand what is happening, but with that test config, I can remove the Okta configs from the application.properties for testing. I _think_ that's what I'm looking for, but maybe after some more research, I can nail things down further.

Comment: after browsing endless internet resources with "it have to be easier" mindset - I settled for your solution wich is the only one i managed to get working off line.